# TestComplete 8 and TFS 2010 Lab Management

Tags: testing, tfs, testcomplete, lab-management

I'm tryng to run TestComplete 8 tests with TFS 2010 Lab Management and I keep getting following error when running tests:

> File extension specified '.tc8test' is not a valid test extension.

I can't seam to find any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install TestComplete (with TFS integration modules) on the Test Agent PC, and the PC where you are configuring your tests (where Visual Studio is installed)?

Comment: Yes, I did on all computers - but eventually we just gave up on this integration.